# keeping page status and result in angular 5 for use with browser back button

Tags: angular

I have quite a number of pages that are search related. If broswer back button is clicked, i want to return to the same previous page. The data comes from a django Rest API.

For now my solution is to save last api called and save it in session storage but I am writing so many session variables for each new component that needs such a thing.

Is there a manageable way to handling such a request?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `queryParams`, so if you build your component based on query params then not only this will work for browsers' back button but also give you the freedom to share the URL as a link.

<strike>Read the query params under `ngOnInit()` and build your model.</strike>

```
this._route
    .queryParams
    .subscribe((params) => {
        // based on the received params -> render/request

     })

// here _route is an ActivateRoute instance
```

**EDIT**

I think you will have to listen to router changes, it is quite possible that the component may not be reInitialized on navigation changes. To handle this, you can use something like in your `ngOnInit()`:

```
this._router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe(() => {
         console.log(this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams);
         // get the queryParams here and then based on some conditions, -> render/request, etc
     })

// here _router is a Router instance and _activatedRoute is an ActivatedRoute instance
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish. Your edit makes more sense. Let me try it and get back to you in a moment.

Comment: @NieSelam: Okay, if you implement this then remember to kill the subscription in `ngOnDestroy` of the component. Assign the `this._router.events...` subscription to a class variable and unsubscribe when the component destroys..